# Zkemkeeper OnDisconnectedEvent is not firing in C#

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkemkeeper

**Background:** *I have [connected a window form application with a bio-metric attendance machine (ZKTeco K20 Model)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started). It has connected but there is an issue with OnDisconncted event.*

I have this code snippet, here onDisconnected event is registered but unfortunately, it is not triggering (whenever i switched off the device or unplug network cable).

```
 public bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)
        {   
            if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
            {
                //65535, 32767
                //if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))//old
                if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 65535))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Connect_Net");
                    // [ Register your events here ]
                    // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a complete list of events
                    objCZKEM.OnConnected += ObjCZKEM_OnConnected;
                    //objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += objCZKEM_OnDisConnected;
                    objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += new _IZKEMEvents_OnDisConnectedEventHandler(objCZKEM_OnDisConnected);
                    objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger;
                    objCZKEM.OnFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnFinger;
                    objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    //objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(objServerInteraction.zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    objCZKEM.OnAlarm += OnAlarm;
                    objCZKEM.OnNewUser += OnNewUser;
                    objCZKEM.OnKeyPress += OnKeyPress;

                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The rest of the event like `OnAttTransactionEx` executing fine but whenever my attendance device (Zketeco) turn off, it didn't fire `objCZKEM_OnDisConnected` event.  Do this event fire on device turn off (attendance machine).? Or I am registering it in wrong way?

Here is the [**link**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started) where I got this code with tutorial.

Comment: `OnDisConnected` could not be fired when your device turned off it always fire when your device disconnected. before turned off you have to disconnect your device so `OnDisConnected` will be fired

Comment: Actually my application don't respond whenever it disconnected with the deivce. Thats why i want this kind of event so that i can establish the connection again.

Comment: what is the meaning of device disconnected?

Comment: did u listen all the events by `ReadRTLog` and `GetRTLog`? in while loop

Comment: what is the meaning of device disconnected => means your device successfully disconnected with your PC

Comment: No I don't know about ReadRTLog and GetRTLog. Provide me links for it, so i study. Further, my device connected with my windows form application. why this event for pC disconnect. ?

Comment: so all of your other events working except `OnDisConnected`?

Comment: Actually i have only use OnAttTransactionEx yet

Comment: so i have to know `OnAttTransactionEx` is fired or not when user verified by device

Comment: Yes, Yes it is working fine as i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: your device is TFT device right?

Comment: I have this https://homeshopping.pk/products/ZKTECO-K20-Attendance-Machine-Price-In-Pakistan.html

Comment: And here is my project link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started

Comment: so add a timer in your form and in Tick event of timer add this code `if (objCZKEM.ReadRTLog(iMachineNumber)) { while (objCZKEM.GetRTLog(iMachineNumber)) { ; } }` and enable your timer from property window and let me know

Comment: `iMachineNumber` is your device id i think it's `1` in your case

Comment: @er-shoaib which timer you are talking about. can you answer it

Comment: windows form timer that is available in toolbox on left side of your windows form.

Comment: I don't know what you want to tell me. Can you define a bit more.

Comment: please go to Menu -> View -> Toolbox -> And from here you will find `timer` then drag and drop this to your windows form and then write my above commented code in `timer1_Tick` event of timer

Answer (score 0):

objCZKEM.OnDisConnected is designed to clean up the resources while the device is soft-disconnected, but not the hard-disconnected. From your program, while you call the objCZKEM.disconnect, you would get the event triggered.

If the device is disconnected by wire, then no events will be triggered.